# Can I install a 2nd Ubuntu next to preexisting Win7 + Ubuntu Wubi installation?

Tags: 11.04, partitioning, dual-boot, wubi

I am running a dualboot with Win7 and Ubuntu 11.o4 Wubi installation.

Now my Wubi installation became to small and I have a boot delay presumably due to Ubuntu being installed on a NTFS partition (i see that via bootchart). Therefore I want to install Ubuntu a second time on a seperate partition. However I want to avoid rendering my machine unbootable or loosing data on the Wubi installation before the new installation is running.

Do you see any problems?

Thanks,
florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot into Ubuntu using the Live CD, from there use Gparted to partition any disks, then install Ubuntu from the CD, I was in the same situation as you and nothing bad happened.

Another option is to back everything up on the Wubi installation using Ubuntu One, then destroy the Wubi and use a fresh Ubuntu installation and everything you need is still there.

Comment: thanks, it indeed worked. however to complete the information, I first thought the WUBI installation was removed from grub. However it is now reachable via first selecting Windows 7 on grub, than the wubi bootloader will appear where you can select Ubuntu or Windows, selcting Ubuntu will give you access to the wubi installation of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

That is entirely possible without destroying anything.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to back up the files on the WUBI installation and boot from the live cd and partition the discs for ubuntu and install on it.when it boots GRUB(the Bootloader) will display the menu through which you can either boot into Windows 7 or Ubuntu.